# Will closing an HTML input break anything or vice versa?

Tags: html, xhtml, input

I have always and will continue to always close an HTML input such as

```
<input type=text />
```

instead of the non-XHTML way

```
<input type=text>
```

But my question is, will either way have any foreseeable problems i.e. cross-browser, mobile device, etc? I've just now noticed that the framework I use generates inputs without a closing tag and I hate have differences between my code and theirs. It's really annoying and ugly.

Comment: outside of code validation, I wouldn't foresee any problems, but I've never done any thorough testing

Comment: You should read [XHTML considered harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml)

Comment: It's not related to your framework, the browser will always do whatever it wants:http://jsbin.com/uhenih/6/edit#preview

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen -XHTML considered harmful was written before HTML5 came into being. In HTML5, both patterns are valid for void elements like `input`. This is, in any case, not XHTML, if it were, the value of the type attribute would need to be quoted.

Comment: I do quote type="text", name="something", etc but whenever I do that here people seem to freak out. So I stop doing it when posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I've never seen a cross-browser problem on account of closing an empty tag in an HTML document.

However, according to [Refactoring HTML](http://www.amazon.ca/Refactoring-HTML-Improving-Existing-Applications/dp/0321503635), older browsers such as Netscape 3 will not parse empty elements properly.

This is because in SGML and some HTML4 parsers, there was support for a syntax "[NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language#NET)" which is similar to the empty tag syntax: (quoted from [XHTML Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml))

> The "/>" empty tag syntax actually has totally different meaning in
>   HTML4. (It's the SHORTTAG minimisation feature known as NET, if I
>   recall the name correctly.) Specifically, the XHTML
>
> ```
> <p> Hello <br /> World </p>
> ```
>
> ...is, if interpreted as HTML4, exactly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> <p> Hello <br>&gt; World </p>
> ```
>
> ...and should really be rendered as:
>
> ```
> Hello
> > World
> ```

So, if you're using a HTML4 `<!DOCTYPE>` and targetting Netscape 3, don't do it! But if you're using HTML5 (or XHTML) there's no harm in closing your empty tags - as a matter of fact in XHTML you have to, or Tim Bray will kill a puppy.

Answer (score 2):

The `input` tag has been unclosed for so long that virtually any system should be able to handle it without a close. If you have declared your document as XHTML, then it will not validate if the tag is not closed, and some XML utilities may have trouble parsing it, but web browsers are designed to be extremely liberal in what they accept.

Comment: @RKS Link/example of an explicitly-closed `<input>` breaking IE? Let's say 6+? (Although 6 is dead to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Having an input tag that is not closed is still valid html, so you should be ok if you have no need to meet the xhtml standard.